# On $||f||_μ := \inf {\{r : μ({\{x : |f(x)| > r }\}) ≤ r}\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

[image]

For (c) I think : Because $\lim_{n \to \infty} μ({\{x : |f(x)-f_n(x)| > r }\}) = 0$ for any $r \ge 0$ thus the inf attains $0$; on the other direction, since inf is zero then the limit is zero?

For (e) I think it intuitively but I don't know how make it rigorous : if $c \ge 1$ then $||cf||_μ=c||f||_μ$ and for $c \le 1$ then $||cf||_μ=||f||_μ$.

I have no idea how to approach this problem especially the definition of $||f||_μ$ seems to be complicated enough to get relations based on that.

**added**- I add my attempt for parts (g) and (h):

Since $\sum_1^{\infty}||g_{k+1}-g_k||_{\mu}< \infty,$ then there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$, and all $\epsilon>0$ : $\sum_1^{\infty}||g_{k+1}-g_k||_{\mu}< \epsilon $. By (b), $||g_n-g_m||_{\mu} \le \sum_{i=m}^{n-1}||g_{i+1}-g_i||_{\mu} < \epsilon$ thus ${\{g_n}\}_n$ is Cauchy and if $d(f,g)=||f-g||_{\mu}$ can be proved to be a metric which by previous parts only remains to prove that if $||f||_{\mu}=0$ then $f=0$ a.e. which I am not sure if it is true. But considering that it's true, there is some $g$ such that $||g_n-g||_{\mu} \to 0$. We construct that $g$ : Our ﬁrst step is to ﬁnd a certain subsequence. Given $ε = 2^{−(j+1)}$, there exists $n_j$ such that if $n, m \ge n_j$, then $||g_n −g_m||_{\mu} \le 2^{−(j+1)}$. WLOG we may assume $n_j \ge n_{j−1}$ for each $j$. Considering $n_0=0$, we hope the limit function will be $\sum_m (g_{n_m} − g_{n_{m−1}}).$  Then (using part (2)), $||g_j||_{\mu} \le \sum_{m=1}^j ||g_{n_m} − g_{n_{m−1}}||_{\mu} \le ||g_{n_1}||+ \frac12$. Hence $g$ is ﬁnite a.e. This proves the absolute convergence for almost every $x$. Set $g(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (g_{n_m} − g_{n_{m−1}}) = \lim_K g_{n_K}$ since we have a telescoping series. But I couldn't figure out how to do for convergence in measure, though.

My question: Am I correct with parts (g) and (h)? Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested for questions (c) and (e) only or for the whole problem?

Comment: @dem0nakos, Of course all part I need to the answers, I think all parts are interesting; I could start just (c) and (e)

Comment: Math SE is not intended to be a "homework dump".  We expect questions here to be narrowly focused, and to include some context.  Please do not use images to convey vital information (as images are not searchable, and are inaccessible to people who use screenreaders).  Advice on [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|130.7469) can be found on the meta site.

Comment: @XanderHenderson It is not homework dump. The O.P. is doing several exercises from a book and preparing for an exam in graduate studies.

Comment: @Ramiro As such, they should have the mathematical maturity to (1) provide context for their question, and (2) narrow their question(s) down to specific questions which fit the SE model of Q&A.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I have written I have written my attempt for some parts and having no idea for other parts. The link (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) you provided doesn't say that if a question has several parts then it is inappropriate to post, it's a personal choice of yours. Having all parts in a single link will help other students 1) have easier access, 2) learn more. I agree with "narrow down" but that's not relevant to this specific question

Comment: @XanderHenderson, also, you closed the question by "This question needs to be more focused" and when you click on "focused" it is written "This can often be fixed by breaking the question into multiple questions".

Comment: @L.G. I have answered questions before that are like this and I have found them to be generally on topic for the reason you mention i.e. that all questions are linked, and therefore it is one question in the end. It feels, with the posting of eight mini questions and you attempt just the two of them, that the rest of the six stand out as mini-PSQs in their own right. That might have been a factor for broadness. I'm not ok with your comment that only serves to insult and dilute the counter argument, I request you to remove it, and we can focus on the relevant issues.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I removed my last comment. For my attempt unfortunately I couldn't do more than 2.

Comment: @L.G. Thank you for the response. I wish to say that I have voted to reopen, but I need you to understand that insults and jibes are going to invariably bias against you in the future, to the extent that people may remove their frustration with negative actions.  I know that Brugman is a difficult book, but it's extremely important that in measure theory that tricks are emphasised and intuitively explained. With that in mind, context such as "if there's a trick, I'd like to know some of the intuition". Or mention a specific issue of yours : "I struggle with rigour", ...

Comment: ... "I have trouble intuitively understanding why $\|f\|_{\mu}$" is defined the way it is. I understand the answer below is nice , but I'd have loved it if the answer was a bit more personalized to adjust to your exact concerns (that weren't provided beyond "solve these"), even though that localizes the answer in the sense that it caters more to you than to other readers, as I just think it gives *you* a better reason to want this question answered, and also helps you fill your context quota. Demanding precisely what you want is also effort : writing that in detail is great context.

Comment: OP: Please do make an effort to make your post more focused. Consider going to a mentor or teacher assistant and requesting they solve eight questions in tandem for you. Would you *really* expect them to do so, or perhaps solve *one* of them and encourage you to go back and think on the other 7? In this case, the guidelines are clear, in that we expect focused single questions, and not eight of them. @XanderHenderson's request is simply in line with this. Kind regards,

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, my question is for parts (g) and (h) and I have made attempts for both. Please be update on the current status. Kind regards,

Answer (score 7):

Well, this is not one question, but eight related questions. Here is the answer for them.

Let us go step by step. First, some notation: we will write $[|f|>r]$ to mean $\{ x : |f(x)|>r \}$.

Let $S= \{ r: \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r \}$. Then, since $\mu$ is non-negative, if $r\in S$ then $r \geq 0$. Note also that, for all $f$, $+\infty \in S$.

**Item (a)** Let $\{r_n\}_n$ be a non-increasing sequence of elements in $\{ r: \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r \}$ such that $r_n \searrow \|f\|_\mu$.

We have that, for all $n$, $\mu([|f|>r_n]) \leq r_n$. We also have that $[|f|>r_n] \nearrow [|f|>\|f\|_\mu]$. So
$$ \mu([|f|>\|f\|_\mu])= \lim_n \mu([|f|>r_n])\leq \lim_n r_n = \|f\|_\mu $$

So $ \mu([|f|>\|f\|_\mu]) \leq \|f\|_\mu $.

**Item (b)** Note that for any $\alpha, \beta >0$,

$$ [|f+g|> \alpha + \beta ] \subseteq [|f|> \alpha ] \cup [|g|> \beta ] $$

So, if $\alpha \in  \{ r: \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r \}$ and $\beta \in \{ r: \mu([|g|>r]) \leq r \} $, then

$$\mu( [|f+g|> \alpha + \beta ] ) \leq \mu( [|f|> \alpha ] ) + \mu( [|g|> \beta ] ) \leq \alpha + \beta$$
So, $\alpha+\beta \in \{ r: \mu([|f + g |>r]) \leq r \}$.

So, for all  $\alpha \in  \{ r: \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r \}$ and $\beta \in \{ r: \mu([|g|>r]) \leq r \} $, we have
$$ \|f+g\|_\mu  =\inf \{ r: \mu([|f + g|>r]) \leq r \} \leq \alpha + \beta $$
Let $\alpha_n \searrow   \inf \{ r: \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r \}  = \|f\|_\mu$ and
$\beta_n \searrow   \inf \{ r: \mu([|g|>r]) \leq r \}  = \|g\|_\mu$. For all $n$, we have
$$ \|f+g\|_\mu   \leq \alpha_n + \beta_n $$
Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, we have $\|f+g\|_\mu \leq \|f\|_\mu + \|g\|_\mu $.

**item (c)** Note that

$f_n \to f$ in measure if and only if, for all $\varepsilon, \delta >0$, there is $N$ such that, if $n > N$, then $\mu([|f_n-f|> \varepsilon])\leq \delta$.

$\|f_n -f\|_\mu \to 0$ if and only if, for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $N$ such that, if $n > N$, then $\mu([|f_n-f|> \varepsilon])\leq \varepsilon$.

It is immediate that $f_n \to f$ in measure $\Rightarrow $  $\|f_n -f\|_\mu \to 0$. Just take $\delta = \varepsilon$.

Now let us prove that  $\|f_n -f\|_\mu \to 0$ $\Rightarrow $ $f_n \to f$ in measure.

Suppose $\|f_n -f\|_\mu \to 0$. Then, for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $N_\varepsilon$ such that, if $n > N_\varepsilon$, then $\mu([|f_n-f|> \varepsilon])\leq \varepsilon$.

Given any $\varepsilon, \delta >0$:

1. If $\varepsilon < \delta$ we have that there is $N_\varepsilon$ such that, if $n> N_\varepsilon$, $\mu([|f_n-f|>\varepsilon])\leq \varepsilon < \delta$.
2. If $\delta \leq \varepsilon$ we have that there is $N_\delta$ such that, if $n> N_\delta$, $\mu([|f_n-f|>\varepsilon])\leq \mu([|f_n-f|>\delta]) \leq \delta$.

So, for all $\varepsilon, \delta >0$, there is $N$ such that, if $n> N$, $\mu([|f_n-f|>\varepsilon]) \leq \delta$. So $f_n \to f$ in measure.

**item (d)**:  Let $S= \{ r: \mu([|c\chi_A|>r]) \leq r \}$.

First, note that $\|0\|_\mu =0$. In fact, if $f =0$, then $\mu([|f|> 0]) = \mu(\emptyset) =0 \leq 0$. So, $0 \in S$. So $\|f\|_\mu=0$ (remember that all elements of $S$ are non-negative).

If $c=0$, then $c\chi_A=0$ and $\|c\chi_A\|_\mu = 0 = \inf\{ c, \mu(A)\}$.

If $c>0$, then for all $r \geq 0$

1. if $r<c$ then $[|c\chi_A|>r] = A$ and then $ r \in S$ if and only if $\m(A) \leq r$;
2. if $r \geq c$  then $[|c\chi_A|>r] = \emptyset$ and $r \in S$.

So, if $\mu(A) < c$ then $\|c\chi_A\|_\mu = \mu(A)$, and if $\mu(A) \geq  c$ then $\|c\chi_A\|_\mu = c$. So we have that $\|c\chi_A\|_\mu  = \inf\{ c, \mu(A)\}$.

**item (e)** Let $S_1=  \{ r: \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r \}$ and $S_c =  \{ r: \mu([|cf|>r]) \leq r \}$.

If $c < 1$ , then $[|cf|>r] \subseteq [|f|>r]$, so if $r \in S_1$, then
$\mu([|cf|>r]) \leq  \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r $
So $S_1 \subseteq S_c$. So
$$ \|c f \|_\mu = \inf S_c \leq \inf S_1 = \| f \|_\mu$$

If $c \geq 1$ , then $[|cf|>cr] = [|f|>r]$, so if $r \in S_1$, then
$\mu([|cf|>cr]) =  \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r \leq cr$, so $cr \in S_c$. So we have $cS_1 \subseteq S_1$ and so, we have
$$ \|c f \|_\mu = \inf S_c \leq \inf cS_1 = c\inf S_1= c\| f \|_\mu$$

So $\|c f \|_\mu  \leq \max \{ \| f \|_\mu, c\| f \|_\mu  \}$.

**item (f)** The statement of this item is missing one condition. As stated, it is false, with a trivial counter-example: let $A$ be a set such that $\mu(A) < \infty$, let $f=\infty \chi_A$. Then for any $c>0$, $cf =f$ and  then $\|cf \|_\mu$ does not converge to zero as $c \to 0$.

The condition missing is that $f$ must be finite a.e.. Suppose $f$ is finite a.e..

So let $B = [|f|=\infty]$. Since $f$ is finite a.e., we have $\mu(B)=0$.

Let $n \in \Bbb N$, we have $ [|f|>n] \subseteq [|f|\geq 0]$ and $ [|f|>n] \searrow B$. So, using the fact that $\mu([|f|\geq 0]) < \infty$, we have
$$ \mu([|f|>n]) \searrow \mu(B)=0$$

Now, given any $\varepsilon >0$, there is $N$ such that if $n>N$ then  $ \mu([|f|>n]) < \varepsilon$.

Take $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{N+1} $ . Then, for any $c$ such that $|c| < \delta$, we have
$$ [|cf|>\varepsilon]= [|f|>\varepsilon/|c|] \subseteq [|f|>\varepsilon/\delta]= [|f|>N+1]$$
So
$$ \mu( [|cf|>\varepsilon]) \leq \mu ([|f|>N+1]) \leq \varepsilon $$
So $\varepsilon \in \{ r: \mu([|cf|>r]) \leq r \}$. So $\|cf\|_\mu \leq \varepsilon$.

So we have prove that, for all  $\varepsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that, if $|c|<\delta$ then $\|cf\|_\mu \leq \varepsilon$.  That means $\|cf\|_\mu \to 0$ as $c \to 0$.

**item (g)**  Let us understand item (g).  It is rather trivial to adapt our solution to item (c) to show that $g_n$ is Cauchy in $\mu$-measure   if and only $g_n$ is Cauchy regarding $\|\cdot\|_\mu$. So, if $g_n$ is Cauchy regarding $\|\cdot\|_\mu$ then

1. there is a function $g$ such that there is a sub-sequence $g_{n_k}$ converging to $g$ a.e. and $g_n$ converges to $g$ in  $\mu$-measure.

The "challenge" in this item is that if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \|g_{k+1} - g_k\|_\mu  < \infty$ then, we have a condition stronger than being a Cauchy sequence  regarding $\|\cdot\|_\mu$ such that  we don't need to take the sub-sequence for the convergence a.e.. Here is a detailed proof:

Let $a_n = \|g_{k+1} - g_k\|_\mu $. From item (a), we have that
$$ \mu([|g_{k+1}-g_k|> a_k ]))\leq a_k$$
Now, note that , for all $r \leq k \leq s $, we have
$$\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ] \subseteq  \left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=k}^{s-1} a_i \right]\subseteq  \bigcup_{i=k}^{s-1} [|g_{i+1}-g_i|> a_i ] \subseteq \bigcup_{i=r}^\infty [|g_{i+1}-g_i|> a_i ]$$

So, for all $s,k$ such that $r \leq k \leq s$, we have
$$\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ] \subseteq  \bigcup_{i=r}^\infty [|g_{i+1}-g_i|> a_i ]$$

So, we have

$$\bigcup_{k \geq r} \bigcup_{s \geq k}\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ] \subseteq  \bigcup_{i=r}^\infty [|g_{i+1}-g_i|> a_i ]$$

So,

$$\mu \left (\bigcup_{k \geq r} \bigcup_{s \geq k}\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ] \right ) \leq  \mu \left (\bigcup_{i=r}^\infty [|g_{i+1}-g_i|> a_i ] \right ) \leq \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i $$

So, for all $r\in \Bbb N$, we have

$$\mu \left (\bigcap_{t \in \Bbb N} \bigcup_{k \geq t} \bigcup_{s \geq k}\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ] \right ) \leq \mu \left (\bigcup_{k \geq r} \bigcup_{s \geq k}\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ] \right ) \leq   \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i $$

Since $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i < \infty$, we have that, for all $r\in \Bbb N$

$$\mu \left (\bigcap_{t \in \Bbb N} \bigcup_{k \geq t} \bigcup_{s \geq k}\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ] \right )= 0$$

So,
$$\mu \left (\bigcup_{r \in \Bbb N}\bigcap_{t \in \Bbb N} \bigcup_{k \geq t} \bigcup_{s \geq k}\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ] \right )= 0$$

Let $A = \bigcup_{r \in \Bbb N}\bigcap_{t \in \Bbb N} \bigcup_{k \geq t} \bigcup_{s \geq k}\left [|g_s -g_k|> \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i \right ]$.

Now, note that,  if $x\in X$ and $x\notin A$, then, for each $r$,
there is $T \in \Bbb N$ such that, for all $s, k$, $T \leq k \leq s $, we have  $|g_s(x) -g_k(x)| \leq \sum_{i=r}^\infty a_i   $.

It follows that $g_n$ is Cauchy a.e., so there is a function $f$ such that $g_n$ converges to $f$ a.e..

However, from 1 in the beginning of this item, we know that there is a function $g$ such that there is a sub-sequence $g_{n_k}$ converging to $g$ a.e. and $g_n$ converges to $g$ in  $\mu$-measure. So $f=g$ a.e.. This concludes the proof of item (g). $\square$

**Item (h)** As stated this item does not mention $\| \cdot \|_\mu$ and it is a trivial consequence of theorems regarding convergence in measure and convergence a.e. (Bruckner 4.2).

I believe the intent in the item was to show that if $g_n$ is Cauchy in  $\| \cdot \|_\mu$, then there is a sub-sequence $g_{n_k}$ that converges both in measure and $\mu$-almost everywhere.

The easiest way to solve it is to adapt our solution of item (c) to show that $g_n$ is Cauchy in $\mu$-measure   if and only $g_n$ is Cauchy regarding $\|\cdot\|_\mu$, and then apply the theorems regarding convergence in measure and convergence a.e. (Bruckner 4.2).

**Remark**: Let $S= \{ r: \mu([|f|>r]) \leq r \}$. We know that, if $r\in S$, then $r \geq 0$. We also know that $+\infty \in S$.

Note that, given $r, t \in [0, +\infty]$, if $r \in S$ and $r \leq t$, we have
$ [|f|>t] \subseteq [|f|>r]$, so we have
$$ \mu([|f|>t] \leq \mu([|f|>r] \leq r$$
So  $t\in S$.

Thus, we have that $S$ is of the form $(a, +\infty]$ or $[a, +\infty]$, for some $a \geq 0$. So, by item (a), $S$ is always of the form $[a, +\infty]$, for some $a \geq 0$. Of course, $a$ is precisely $\|f\|_\mu$.

Comment: @L.G. I have added the answer to the sixth item (item(f)).

Comment: You note in your first line that this is not one question, but eight.  In the future, please refrain from answering such questions.  The advisable course of action to to vote to close such a question as being too broad, then help the asker to narrow down their question to a single idea.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Did you downvote my answer because of this?? It is not fair, I was just trying to help the OP, and it took me time to prepare the answer.  I put the comment in the begining of the answer exactly to warn the OP that this is not a single question.

Comment: If you do not like having your answers downvoted, then please try to consider the health of the **site** in addition to the needs of the original asker.  If a question does not adhere to the site guidelines, then it is incumbent upon you (as someone who wishes to post an answer) to help the asker improve their question *before* you answer it.  If a question is not appropriate for Math SE, then any answer to that question is "not useful", and it is therefore entirely fair to downvote said answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  The OP is preparing for an exam in his graduate studies.  He is doing several exercises fro a book. But he can not ask here the exercise he does not know how to do... Humm.. Ok.. I make me think what StackExechange is good for, if it is not for helping students.

Comment: @Ramiro The motivations of the asker are not relevant in this case.  The question is too broad, and is not appropriate for Math SE.  Answering such a question is equally inappropriate.  If your interest is in helping the asker, then please help them to improve their question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson My interest was to help the student to prepare for his exam, which is not exactly the same thing as helping him to comply to StackExchange. Math standards. I will send him by e-mail the the answer he needs and I will delete the answer here to preserve the "purity" of Math SE. So everybody will be happy.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, 1- By "we" in *"We expect..."* you probably mean yourself; I believe having some threshold reputation to be moderator still should not be used to close a question by *one* vote. Closing a question still needs 5 votes. For closing a question by one-person decision **you need to provide a citation from the rules of MSE site that asking a question of several joint parts is inappropriate and not misuse your authority.**

Comment: @XanderHenderson, 2- The question is inside one single exercise and because I have problem with many parts then I had send it in 8 question and based on my previous experience in MSE I am certain that another "moderator" would close for why not gathering them in one? **Spreading this to several question will not be useful for other students that want to learn from this question, too.** 3- I only agree with one abjection you made : writing the question not posting an image of it which I will edit it after my exam.

Comment: In (b) : $\alpha \ge ||f||$ and $\beta \ge ||g||$ thus $\alpha + \beta \ge ||f||+||g||$; also $\alpha + \beta \ge ||f+g||$; no more info I couldn't find to conclude that $||f+g|| \le ||f||+||g||$?

Comment: From $\alpha + \beta \ge ||f+g||$ we get the conclusion that $||f+g|| \le ||f||+||g||$. Later today I will add more details to help clarifying this step.

Comment: Thank you Ramiro, I think I add all my questions for all parts then post them together for once edit easier for you. Within one or two hours I'll do.

Comment: I checked through all parts I couldn't find even a tiny flaw; Thank you very much indeed! I was going to bounty this question first because it was lengthy, then more because the answer is great. I need for the question to be opened though. I am trying answer the rest then the question will probably be open.

Comment: @L.G.  I have added a **Remak** to my answer that you may find interesting.

Comment: Hi Ramiro, the flag has been removed so bounty click is active now. I don't feel that I've done the rest two parts well, I would appreciate it if you please have a look on them if you have time. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @LG Ok. I will do, later today.

Comment: @LG Done. Please, take a look.

Comment: Thank you Ramiro, I will study them both soon.